Why is usbguard-notifier not showing notifications anymore?
usbguard-notifier is not showing a notification popup anymore when plugging in a USB device. How to find out why? Debian 12 with KDE and Wayland. Notifications did show up until recently. If it's supposed to work with Wayland maybe there are some notifications-related logs to check.
No output is shown when I run usbguard-notifer in the console and connect the usb device. I do not have that or any device id explicitly set to blocked so it should show a prompt notification asking for allow or block the device like it used to when connecting the usb device.

sudo journalctl -b | grep usbguard-notifier shows this as the latest output for things hours ago but does not have any output for the latest tries where I inserted the usb device a few more times for testing:
usbguard-notifier[25776]: Connection has been established
usbguard-notifier[25776]: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
usbguard-notifier[25776]:   what():  Failed to show notification
                                                      #7  0x000055e4e6caa8ba n/a (usbguard-notifier + 0x48ba)
                                                      #8  0x000055e4e6cac8db n/a (usbguard-notifier + 0x68db)
                                                      #4  0x000055e4e6cab569 n/a (usbguard-notifier + 0x5569)
                                                      #7  0x000055e4e6cab661 n/a (usbguard-notifier + 0x5661)
drkonqi-coredump-processor[26202]: "/usr/bin/usbguard-notifier" 25776 "/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.usbguard-notifi.1000.longid1.25776.longid.zst"

sudo journalctl -b | grep usbguard shows (replaced usb device name, serialid and longhash):
usbguard-daemon[1120]: uid=0 pid=1038 result='SUCCESS' device.rule='block id 042a:6257 serial "serialid" name "usb device name" hash "longhash" parent-hash "longhash2" via-port "1-3" with-interface 08:06:50 with-connect-type "hotplug"' device.system_name='/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3' type='Device.Remove'
usbguard-daemon[1120]: uid=0 pid=1038 result='SUCCESS' device.rule='block id 042a:6257 serial "serialid" name "usb device name" hash "longhash" parent-hash "longhash2" via-port "1-3" with-interface 08:06:50 with-connect-type "hotplug"' device.system_name='/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3' type='Device.Insert'
usbguard-daemon[1120]: uid=0 pid=1038 result='SUCCESS' device.system_name='/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3' target.new='block' device.rule='block id 042a:6257 serial "serialid" name "usb device name" hash "longhash" parent-hash "longhash2" via-port "1-3" with-interface 08:06:50 with-connect-type "hotplug"' target.old='block' type='Policy.Device.Update'

I have all the available upgrades installed and rebooting does not help - still no notification popups like it used to be.
Update: they do show up again now but I have no idea why.


How to find out why?

Like any systemd user service, it will be monitorable using systemctl status --user, and its log appear in journalctl --user. If you want to filter for messages from this boot only, journalctl -b --user -u usbguard.
It is supposed to work with wayland. In fact, it shouldn't care at all. It doesn't interact with the display system at all; it uses libnotify to send notification via dbus to the component that displays notifications.

That command does not show any output (with sudo) but sudo journalctl -b | grep usbguard-notifier works. It shows what(): Failed to show notification with 4 lines of mostly hexcode-things beneath it for an earlier try. It does not show that or any other messages for the usb device inserts that I just tried. When greping for usbguard it shows the device get blocked. systemctl status --user lists usbguard-notifier but I don't know what you refer to with monitoring there (filepath is fine) and it's shown in the KDE process manager anyway along with usbguard-daemon + usbguard-dbus processes.

the exact outputs you're seeing would definitely enhance your question! I'd edit that to include that.
